# Основные принципы ООП (Полиморфизм и абстракция)

Tags: ооп

Я изучил основные принципы ООП, но полиморфизм и абстракция для меня остались не до конца поняты. Можно привести определение с примерами для полиморфизма и абстракции?

Comment: Ну если вы изучили, то вы видели и определение и примеры. А если в них что-то было непонятно, то спрашивайте что именно непонятно

Comment: Можете посмотреть здесь https://systems-ez.ru/index.php/ru/concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ссылаясь на книгу Кори Альтхоффа *"Сам себе программист"***
**Абстракция (обобщение)**
**Абстракция -** Это процесс "отнятия или удаления у чего-то характеристик с целью **сведения его к набору основных**, существенных характеристик". В ООП используется, когда объекты моделируются с использованием классов, а ненужные **подробности опускаются**.
    
Допустим мы создали модель человека. Человек многосложный у него есть цвет волос, цвет глаз, рост вес, пол и др. Если для представления человека вы создадите класс, некоторые из этих данных могут оказаться не важными в рамках задачи, которую вы пытаетесь решить. Примером абстракции может быть создание класса *Person* c опущением некоторых свойств, например цвета глаз или веса. Объекты *Person*, которые создает ваш класс, являются абстракциями (обобщениями) людей. Это представление человека обрезанное до основных характеристик.
**Полиморфизм (разновидовость)**
**Полиморфизмом** называют "способность(в программировании) представлять один и тот же интерфейс для разных базовых форм(типов данных)". Интерфейс - это функция или метод.
**Пример на языке python 3:**

```
print("Hello world")
print(200)
print(200.1)
```

Comment: *на языке python* -> *на языке python 3*.